# MongoDB script hangs after a number of iterations over a cursor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, cursor

I have written a script in JavaScript that iterates a cursor by batches. First I use `cursor.batchSize(500)` to set the batch size to 500. Then I use `cursor.objsLeftInBatch()` to determine how many objects are left in the current batch. I process them with a command, and start the process again, until `cursor.hasNext()` returns a *falsy* value.

This works *great*, until it processes some number of elements. Probably millions. Then the script completely freezes for hours. But that's OK, because after that time it recovers and works nicely again. But, after processing another chunk of elements, it freezes and refuses to go back to work. I am waiting for the process to continue as I am writing here, but it has been already a whole day. The script seems to be doing something (it *is* using CPU), but I don't know what is the script spending all this time on. Just to be clear: neither the RAM nor the disk are saturated.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you included debug statements in your script?

Comment: @BatScream There are no debug statements in the script.

Comment: Please add debug statements to see which operation in your code takes time and gets stuck. You can use the `print` statement.

Comment: `cursor.next()` and `cursor.hasNext()` are the only mongodb operations I am using. Why should any of these operations block at all?

Comment: That's what we want to determine - which operation is blocking and why, so it can be fixed. It might be the driver, the server, or your code. Please try to determine what is actually blocking in the script, post some code, and include the driver and MongoDB version.